# "npx create-next-app@latest" is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terminal, npx

[image]

I'm using Macbook Pro terminal, and I'm connecting an EC2 SSH instance from AWS. The instance type is t2.micro, and the platform is Ubuntu. When I run "npx create-next-app@latest", my screen is stuck like this for hours. I have attempted downloading the dependencies separately, i.e. downloading eslint before running “npx create-next-app@latest”. My AWS server is in Asia Pacific (Sydney), and my node version is “v20.11.0” and my npm version is “10.4.0”. Considering that my node and npm is already the most updated version, I do not understand why my screen is stuck like this. Can you please help me find the error?